# loop through array names using for loop python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 arrays that is already defined:

```
array1[:,:,:]
array2[:,:,:]
array3[:,:,:]
```

In Unix I would do the following:

```
for ((i=1;i<4;i++))
do 
a = array$i[:,:,:]*1000
echo a 
done
```

This would give:

```
array1[:,:,:]
array2[:,:,:]
array3[:,:,:]
```

How can I do this in Python in a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the completely legit nice way? put the 3 arrays in a list and iterate through that list.

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 5]
a3 = [6]

array_list = [a1, a2, a3]

for a in array_list:
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
```

That is the ideal way to do it, you should not ideally be fiddling with names. However, is it possible if you want to using globals.

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 5]
a3 = [6]

for i in range(1, 4): #range is right exclusive
    print(globals()['a' + str(i)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
```

However, just because it is possible does not mean it is recommended.

Comment: Thanks.. it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this in python it makes more sense to use a `dict` like so (and I'm ignoring that `[:,:,:]` is a syntax error):

```
arrays = {}
arrays[1] = [:,:,:]
arrays[2] = [:,:,:]
arrays[3] = [:,:,:]

for i in arrays:
    a = arrays[i] * 1000
    print(a)
```

Comment: `array1[:,:,:]` is a valid syntax for numpy arrays.